# Запись исполняющего файла в "загрузки"

Tags: bitbucket, git

Как можно после каждого push'а заливать определенный файл в "загрузки" на bitbucket? А то файл далеко и постоянно лазить в исходник не удобно.

Answer (score 1):

Не уверен, что bitbucket позволяет подобное, но, вообще, это решается post-receive хуком.

Comment: Разве bitbucket позволяет запускать hook'и?

Comment: Можно ли вообще хоть как нибудь программно загрузить туда файл?